# Where is the location of the OS X 10.5 user wallpaper

Tags: macos, operating-system, filesystems, desktop-wallpaper

I was just wondering where the `/File/System/Location/` of a users current wallpaper is stored in OS X 10.5. Something like how the default login windows wallpaper is stored at `/System/Library/CoreServices/DefaultDesktop.jpg`

Comment: No, there's a programming answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the path:  /Library/Desktop Pictures where root is your computers name.  That's where it's located on my OS X 10.5

Answer (score 0):

Information about the current desktop picture of each desktop (i.e. monitor) is available through the System Events AppleScript interface.  For example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    get picture of its first desktop
end tell
```

Comment: does OSX pull the image from there. My question is where does the system keep a consistently named cache copy of the image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "cache copy". The System Events interface allows a script to access or change the picture path for each desktop.  The Desktop & Screen Saver preference panel is the conventional GUI interface to this.  Note, if there are multiple monitors, each is considered a desktop and can have its own background.  Also, a user can also select a folder of pictures (rather than a single picture) for each desktop and specify a time period for the pictures to be automatically rotated on the desktop. So there may not be a single static image.

Comment: See the Desktop Suite section of System Events.sdef in the AppleScript  Script Editor.app for more details of the script interface.  And perhaps if you could elaborate on what you are trying to do, a better answer could be formulated.